# Creating summary table using ArcMap 10.2 Report Wizard?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, reports

I've been having a play and reading the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_are_reports_in_ArcGIS/004v00000001000000/) about a part of ArcMap I don't really use and that is the Reports. I thought I would teach myself a bit more about this by creating a simple report, for which I have spectacularly failed!

I have a point dataset, say with 100 points and there is a text field that gives each point a type. For arguments sake I have types A, B, C and D.

I've been trying to create a single page that would give a count for each type, something that the [Summary Statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) can do.  The end result would be a nice looking report with a simple table like:

```
Type  Count
A      25
B      25
C      30
D      20
```

That is it! Nothing more complex. Have I misunderstood what a report is actually about? I've tried setting Group Levels, Summary Function to count and Summary Group properties and have not succeeded in creating a simple table.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it only provides this functionality if you group by a field, so you need at least 2 fields in your data.  So in short, the answer is no.  Not the way you want to do it.  The main function of the reporting tools is to allow you to summarise data by groups.

Below I've tried to outline the process of creating the summary you want using a group.

I've created a single point feature class with 2 fields.  One called "Type" as text.  The other called "Number" as short field (this 2nd field could be whatever you want - could even be blank).

[image]

I will summarise this by the "Type" field.

- Start the Report Wizard (View > Reports > Create Report)
- Select both the "Type" and "Number" fields for the report and click "Next".
- Now create a group for the report based on the "Type" field. 
  To do this double click on "Type" under "Report Fields:"

[image]

- It should look like this.

[image]

- Keep clicking on "Next" and select your style, layout, orientation
  etc... -I've left everything as the default.
- On the last screen select to "Modify the report's design" and then
  click "Finish".

[image]

- The "Report Designer" will now open.
- From the left hand "Design Elements" menu, select the "Text Box" and
  draw one anywhere on your report (you will move this later)
- Now that you've drawn a box, you can drag it into the header called
  "gfType" on the report.  This is the field that we grouped by.

[image]

- It should look like this
  [image]
- Now make sure this new text box is selected, you will see an "Element
  Properties" window in the right hand side.  Under "Data", set the
  "Data Field" to "Type" - This is the field we want to summarise by.
  Now inder Under "Summary":
- Set the "Distinct Field" to "Type"
- Set the "Summary Function" to "Count"
- Set the "Summary group" to "ghType" (or whatever your group is called).
- Set the "Summary Running" to "Group"
- Set the "Summary Type" to "Sub Total"

[image]

- Now click on the "Run Report" button (Top left)

You will see that the data has been grouped by "Type" and underneath each group there is a count of the total number of items in that group

[image]

Comment: Hmmm well Dan you have got further than I did but as you say its not quite what I want, I don't want all the individual rows. It's been good to see your workflow. I'm officially ready to punch my monitor and curse ArcMap, thank God it's Friday!  I did have one idea over lunch and that was to create the summary table first and report that but that seems to defeat all the summary capabilities that the Report seems to offer.

Comment: If you're just creating a summary table, you could just create your own Report template in the Layout Window and insert the summary table into it (even if you don't have a map in there).  It seems like you're trying to do the impossible (or using the wrong tools for the job...)

Answer (score 1):

The summary table steps outlined above were right on but you needed one more step to create the summary table WITHOUT all the individual rows.

Select the "Number" box within the detail, set its Can Grow behavior to "False", set its size to 0, 0 in. Next set the Detail area's Can Grow behavior to "False", set its Height to 0.

Your summary table should be as you wanted.

Even simpler - click on detail area header and go to its properties. Under Visible set to False!